# using .astype() isnot saving the changes permanently. I have tried assigning columns names to the changes but still no changes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dtype

`.astype()` not changing dtypes permanently. Assigning columns either showing 'Columns must be same length as key' or not showing any error but also not saving the dtypes change.

```
df[['male','education','currentSmoker','BPMeds','prevalentStroke','prevalentHyp','diabetes','CVD']] = df.astype({'male':'object','education':'object','currentSmoker':'object','BPMeds':'object','prevalentStroke':'object','prevalentStroke':'object','prevalentHyp':'object','diabetes':'object','CVD':'object'})
```

Comment: Why did you filter columns on the left-hand side but not the right-hand side? The assignment needs to match up. Just do `df = df.astype({'male': 'object', ... })`

Comment: Note that the dictionary you pass into `astype` does not filter columns. It just defines the `column:dtype` mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want choose columns and create new dataframe, then you can use:

```
Newdf = df[['male','education','currentSmoker']

Newdf = Newdf.astype({'male':'object','education':'object','currentSmoker':'object'})
```